# How does SASL Anonymous work with xmpp?

Tags: xmpp

I was studying about the SASL Anonymous mechanism in xmpp.
What I found was the XEP-0175 for best practices to use XEP-0175.

The SASL Anonymous authentication mechanism allocates you a UUID based jid and then allows you access to the server.

Suppose there are two users Alice and Bob.
Alice authenticates via SASL Anonymous and is assigned temporary jid 
Bob authenticates via SASL Anonymous and is assigned temporary jid

How does Alice come to know about Bob's jid and Bob comes to know of Alice's jid?

In essence how is communication established between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Users are anonymous, that's the purpose of SASL anonymous. So, this is not to use for long running, persistent relation with other users.

The use case for Anonymous authentication is not the whole scope of the XMPP usage but is more limited.

It is useful for example to receive events, for example coming from a pubsub channel, over a short period of time, on a web page.
It can be also used to grant access to chat rooms without the need to create an XMPP account.
Another example, is that one of your user may invite another one by email for a short-lived one time conversation.